# Dynamic NameResolver that the load balancer will honor?

Tags: grpc

So I am working on a gRPC based remoting framework and I have created my own service registry that my services registers in when they come up. Of course I would like the client to lookup the server from the using a custom NameResolver.

So this is working now but since I want to change the service registry at runtime (for example to support rolling upgrades), I would like the NameResolver to keep checking and when a change occurs I want it to update the registry by doing onUpdate. The question is, can I do this and will the gRPC framework honor the update?

So my understading is that the load balancer checks the list of ResolvedServerInfo so it knows what to load balance between. But from that point I am unclear how this is intendent to work. Does it check each time and is it allowed to keep updating the NameResolver. Listener?

I hope this is the case since it is a crucial part of the service discovery I am trying to implement.

Thanks

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

`NameResolver` is designed to get push based updates rather than polling for changes in addresses.  In order to accomplish what you want, you'll need to set up a timer to periodically refresh names in your customer name resolver.